# How to add Holoviews chart in a Bokeh figure?

Tags: pandas, bokeh, sankey-diagram, holoviews

Let us suppose that I created a Bokeh figure as such

```
fig = figure(title="Any title", width=1600, height=800)
```

and that I created a Holoviews Sankey chat from a Pandas DataFrame as such

```
sankey = hv.Sankey(data)
sankey.opts(width=1200, height=600)
```

How can I insert that chart in that figure?

Comment: `hv.Sankey` can generate it's own Bokeh figure that you can access, and you could insert that figure into a Bokeh *layout*, but it's not possible to "insert" one figure into another existing figure.

Comment: See http://holoviews.org/user_guide/Plotting_with_Bokeh.html#working-with-bokeh-directly for how to generate a Bokeh figure from a HoloViews object like `sankey`.

Comment: The problem is that if I simply say

`sankey = hv.Sankey(data)`
`fig = hv.render(sankey)`
`show(fig)`

I get a plot larger than the canvas, so I have to zoom to see the whole plot.
The problem are the labels on the right side. They are "truncated".
I need to tell that the plot itself is 1600 wide but inside a canvas that is 1800 wide. How?